# Analyzing permutations in R

Tags: r, permutation

I can get all permutations of letters a-e by:

```
> library(gtools)
> permutations(5,5, letters[1:5])
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  [1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e" 
  [2,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "e"  "d" 
  [3,] "a"  "b"  "d"  "c"  "e" 
  [4,] "a"  "b"  "d"  "e"  "c" 
  [5,] "a"  "b"  "e"  "c"  "d" 
  [6,] "a"  "b"  "e"  "d"  "c" 
  [7,] "a"  "c"  "b"  "d"  "e" 
  [8,] "a"  "c"  "b"  "e"  "d" 
.....
```

But how do I know, for each row, how many letters in the row are in their proper place?

Edit:
Thanks for your replies. I used microbenchmark see the speed:

```
> n=7
> f1 <- function() {A= permutations(n,n, letters[1:n]); table(apply(A, 1, function(u) sum( u == letters[1:n] )))}
> f2 <- function() {A= permutations(n,n, letters[1:n]); rowSums(A==letters[1:n][col(A)])}
> f3 <- function() {A <-permutations(n,n); rowSums(A==col(A))}
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), unit="relative")
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f1() 1.426850 1.426050 1.424601 1.428461 1.410686 1.727781   100
 f2() 1.076791 1.074002 1.071137 1.065674 1.069168 1.071190   100
 f3() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
```

I had accepted apply answer since it was clearly understandable.

Keeping permutation function outside:

```
> n=8
> library(gtools)
> A= permutations(n,n, letters[1:n]);
> B <-permutations(n,n); 
> f1 <- function() {table(apply(A, 1, function(u) sum( u == letters[1:n] )))}
> f2 <- function() {rowSums(A==letters[1:n][col(A)])}
> f3 <- function() {rowSums(B==col(B))}
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), unit="relative")
Unit: relative
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 f1() 79.426189 72.674500 40.296357 68.896710 43.559159 6.269005   100
 f2()  3.440729  3.614968  2.807806  3.589499  2.740272 1.349151   100
 f3()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000   100
>
```

Comment: why not keep it as a numbers? `perms<-permutations(5,5); rowSums(perms==col(perms))`

Comment: I would have kept the permutations outside the functions, when testing the efficiency. Then you will probably see a huge difference in time.

Comment: @JR: You are right. See my edit above.

Comment: +1 for the comparison of the different solutions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might work :

```
library(gtools)
A <- permutations(5,5, letters[1:5])
apply(A, 1, function(u) sum( u == letters[1:5] ))
```

We obtain

```
head(data.frame(A,n=apply(A, 1, function(u) sum( u == letters[1:5] ))))
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 n
# 1  a  b  c  d  e 5
# 2  a  b  c  e  d 3
# 3  a  b  d  c  e 3
# 4  a  b  d  e  c 2
# 5  a  b  e  c  d 2
# 6  a  b  e  d  c 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do: (Inspired from @J.R.'s comments)

```
  A <- permutations(5,5, letters[1:5])
  rowSums(A==letters[1:5][col(A)])
  #[1] 5 3 3 2 2 3 3 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 2 3 1 1 3 1 1 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 1
  #[38] 0 2 1 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 3 1 2 1 1 2 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
  #[75] 2 1 0 0 2 1 3 2 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 2 0 0 1 2 2 3 1 1 0 1 0
  #[112] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

#### Explanation

Just for the convenience, I am taking a subset of `A`

```
  A1 <- head(A)
  col(A1)
  #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  #[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
  #[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
  #[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
  #[4,]    1    2    3    4    5
  #[5,]    1    2    3    4    5
  #[6,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

`letters[1:5][col(A1)]`, is similar to `rep(letters[1:5], each=nrow(A1))` because the numeric index created by `col(A1)` and the column wise operation make sure `letters[1:5]` are replicated.  The first element of `letters[1:5]` i.e. `a` fills all the `1`s of `col(A1)`. Similarly, `b`s in `2`s etc of `col(A1)`

```
  letters[1:5][col(A1)]
  #[1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "d"
  #[20] "d" "d" "d" "d" "d" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e"

  rep(letters[1:5], each=nrow(A1))
 # [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "d"
 #[20] "d" "d" "d" "d" "d" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e"
```

In the comparsion `A1==letters[1:5][col(A1)]`, both the `rhs` and `lhs` of `==` have the same `length` (i.e. `length(A1)#[1] 30`, `length(letters[1:5][col(A1)])#[1] 30`), so the comparison will be elementwise and you get the result

```
  A1==letters[1:5][col(A1)]
  #    [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
  #[1,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  #[2,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  #[3,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  #[4,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  #[5,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  #[6,] TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Now, why `A1==letters[1:5]` it gives a different result is because of how the recycling of elements occur.

```
   A1==letters[1:5] 
   #     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
   #[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
   #[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
   #[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   #[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
   #[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
   #[6,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The comparison above is similar to comparing `c(A1)` and `rep(letters[1:5], nrow(A1))`

```
  c(A1)
  #[1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "d" "d" "e" "e" "d"
  #[20] "e" "c" "e" "c" "d" "e" "d" "e" "c" "d" "c"

  rep(letters[1:5], nrow(A1))
  #[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "c" "d"
  #[20] "e" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

If you want to make use of the recycling, you could do:

```
 t(t(A1)==letters[1:5])
 #     [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
 # [1,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 # [2,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 # [3,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 # [4,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 # [5,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 # [6,] TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: +1, but still don't get the reason to convert it to letters, it will be faster without.

Comment: @akrun: Can you add some explanation regarding why A==letters[1:5][col(A)] gives a different output than A==letters[1:5] . rowSums for second code is 1,1,1,1,1,1,.... I tried to check ?col but it is not clear. col(A) has 1,2,3,4,5 in all rows; why is that needed?